# Prove [0,1]x[0,1) isn't a linear continuum.

Tags: general-topology

Well I know that the problem is with the least upper bound property, but I can't find a way to prove it.

**Important: We are working with the dictionary-order topology.**

Comment: $[0,1)$ doesn't have the least upper bound property. Can you prove that?

Comment: Well if we take a set like (1/2,1) it isn't bounded, so we can't use the least bounded property. And the set that are upper bounded must be like (a,1 - epshilon) which it least upper bound will be 1- epshilon no?

Comment: You haven't specified an order on your set. I assume you want the lexicographic order?

Comment: Yes of course, I have edit right now the post

Comment: @Alvaro I would just add that the bracket notation $[0,1)$ tells you that the least upper bound is $1$ and the greatest lower bound is $0$. It's easy to overthink things at this level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=\{(0,t): t \in [0,1)\}$ is bounded above but has no supremum in $[0,1]\times [0,1)$: for every upper bound we can find a strictly smaller upper bound.

As an aside: $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ *is* a linear continuum (the lexicographically ordered square) and also $X \times [0,1)$ when $X$ is well-ordered (gives the so-called *long line* when $X$ is the first uncountable ordinal).